# What was the Shita of the Rema

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, rama

The beit yosef has a very clear Shita. 
There are 3 important poskim:rosh.,rif,and rambam.

He goes after the majority of these Poskim in case of a machloket.

When looking into the rema(darkei moshe) it looks very chaotic.

It looks like he brings every posek known at his time and tries to compromise between them.

Is there a certain order in his Psakim?
What was his Shita? 
Are there any scholarly articles regarding this?

Comment: The better question is how the BY was allowed to make up out of thin air an arbitrary algorithm for paskining everything in Judaism. Borderline reforming...

Comment: It is not correct that *Beis Yosef* always *paskins* like the majority vote of his 3. (e.g. I believe he holds we put 3 *matzas* on the table like the Rosh against both Rambam and Rif.) -- but he does do it most of the time.

Comment: @gt6989b True. Sometimes he even rules against all three in favor of another rishon.

Answer (score 1):

The Ramma outlines his intent in his forward to Toras Chatas. He says he is writing a compendium of the modern works upon whom the practices of his times were observed. He says he is not competing with Rav Yosef Kaaro who's work spread all over the world. He is simply pointing out the places where if someone would open the Shulchan Aruch for a ruling, he would undo the minhagim that were practiced in those countries.

This seems to be in stark contrast to the Reb Yosef Kaaro, in his forward to his Beis Yosef on the Tur, who although he did bring modern sources when the classic ones did not discuss a subject, his express intent was a return to the basics and uncovering sources from the three pillars of halcha, the Riff, Rambam and Rosh. He limited his halakhic ruling to simplistic basic laws.

These differences show in their respective works as the Beis Yosef appears as a 'lamdan' discussing and clarifying, and the Ramma ends up as a 'milaket', a gatherer of ideas, without getting as much into foundations and theories.

Comment: "express intent was a return to the basics" More like his express intent was to be too lazy to try and work out the Halacha himself. That's basically how he describes it in his Hakdama.

Comment: @Double calling it lazy sounds too nasty for me to agree with you.

Comment: Say it or don't say it, it's basically what he says. And I'm not the first person to call him out on it, see the Hakdama to Darkei Moshe. Why are you quoting the Hakdama to Toras Chatas anyway?

Comment: @Double method to the madness, as per the question. The method was (trumpets blaring tadada!) there was no method. Simply quoting sources for established practice. Imagine if you wrote a book on today's practices. Well This is like the mishna berurah, this is like aruch hashulchan etc etc

Comment: @Double And i don't think it was laziness. He wanted to write an addendum to a classic work. He choose the Tur which already did the legwork of quoting the most opinions. This made life easier for the reader as well as the writer.

Comment: Working off the Tur doesn't mean he can't come up with psakim by himself. Anyone can paskin halacha using an algorithm. It takes a gadol to issue real psak.

Comment: @Double yesh li maareh makom chashuv. This one opened my eyes to appreciate the mechaber. In hilchos peyos harosh he says since there are so many opinions, None of whom agree with each other, we must be stringent like all opinions! So it seems that his basic rule was not just to find a multiplicity of opinions and rule with that against the minority. Part of 'Rov' is the fact that we have numerous rabbis agreeing on one idea. He didn't went to rule as a matter of anivus.

Comment: @Double In fact believe the story or not, the chida says there were three who we worthy to write the accepted code of law. But the beis yosef was chosen due to his extreme humility.